# Making ArcGIS Online gallery completely public?

Tags: arcgis-online

I have created a map gallery in arcgis.com.  All the content is public, but when I send my friend the link, he is unable to access it and it looks private.

Can arcgis.com galleries be totally public?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your Organizational settings, go to Gallery and pick what Group you want to make public.  Now, make sure all of the maps and any information that you want to share is also in that group.  Just make sure that in the Group settings, the group is public.

You can then just share the link to the group.